# How does the Wigner function differ from quantum distribution functions?

Tags: quantum-statistics, spin-statistics, wigner-transform

I understand that Wigner functions are quantum-mechanical phase-space distribution functions (quasi-distribution to be more specific). For spin-1/2 particles the Wigner function is a $4\times 4$ matrix. However the Fermi-Dirac distribution function is a scalar quantity. One can write up a relativistic form of FD distribution function. But too is a scalar after all. I have seen some articles, where these two are connected by writing the Wigner function in terms of Clifford algebra and then define each of the components in terms of the FD distribution function. I don't understand that completely.

I think there is a difference, in interpretation between Wigner function and FD statistics for spin-1/2 particles and, not just in mathematical formulation. But I am not sure what it is.

Comment: FD distributions in phase space? Can you give a reference for this? The mainstream one depends on energy only. Can you also give the precise Wigner function, attested, you are talking about?

Comment: See equation 5 of [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03226.pdf) for the FD distribution function. We express the energy as a dot product of fluid velocity and particle momenta, which at local rest frame (u=(1,0,0,0)) is basically the energy. As for the precise form of the Wigner function, I am not aware of it. But may be the following references may help. [link](https://inspirehep.net/files/2648fb526574d740318df221f1e09cca).

Comment: ? Your first link  admits it is *not* in phase space, as its expression involves the 4-velocity, not coordinate; and your second link, for diagonal WFs, is a scalar. Are you *positive* you are not comparing apples and cockroaches, lured by the linguistic coincidence of the term "distribution"?

Comment: $f_0$ in the link 1 is function of (x,p). So isn't it a distribution function in phase-space? Also in equation 8 of link 2 it appears to be a 4x4 matrix. Isn't that so? The gamma matrices in the R.H.S. of 8 in link 2 are 4x4 matrices right? the index $\mu$ over the gamma matrices are summed but the products are still matrices I believe. The first term  'F' is multiplied with 4x4 identity matrix. Maybe I am unable to communicate the issue.

Comment: Probably. (8) is a computational device. The autocorrelation function Fourier transform in (1) for α=β appears like a scalar, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. it appears as a scalar indeed. :)